# Запуск с правами администратора программы написанной с помощью Code::Blocks

Tags: windows, mingw, codeblocks

Для разработки использую Code::Blocks MinGW под Windows. Моей программе требуются права администратора.

Как программно запросить эти права у пользователя?

Прочитал что для этого нужен манифест, куда можно прописать обязательный запуск с правами администратора. Куда нужно его добавить и как использовать?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
        <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="xXx" type="win32"/>
        <description>xXx</description>
            <dependency>
                <dependentAssembly>
                    <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" />
                </dependentAssembly>
            </dependency>
        <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
            <security>
                <requestedPrivileges>
                    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
                </requestedPrivileges>
            </security>
        </trustInfo>
    </assembly>
```

а в код добавлять как-то так:

```
С++IDR_XPMANIFEST MANIFEST "xpmanifest.xml"
```

---

Для семёрки манифест следующий:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> 
  <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"> 
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
      <application> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
        <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 --> 
          <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/> 
      </application> 
    </compatibility>
  </assembly>
```

Comment: ответы можно редактировать с помощью кнопки [edit].

Comment: если мне для C, а не для плюсов, никакой разници нет?

Answer (score 0):

1. Code::Block тут абсолютно непричём. Можете писать программу хоть в
   блокноте.
2. ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ  никогда, ни при каких обстоятельствах, не может кому-то дать права администратора.
3. Вы не указали самое главное обстоятельство - в какой именно ОС собираетесь это сделать? Ведь решение проблемы целиком определяется используемой ОС

Судя по тому, что Вы упомянули MinGW, то речь идёт о Windows. Cразу скажу, что для этого варианта я не знаю решения. Если же речь идёт о *NIX системах, то там нужно действовать следующим образом:

1. Обычный пользователь создаёт приложение
2. Root объявляет испольнимый файл этого приложения своей собственностью.
3. Root взводит бит смены ID пользователя у этого файла.

Тогда, при запуске этого приложения рядовым пользователем, произойдёт установка действующего ID по ID хозяина файла. А хозяином файла является root. Таким образом, в рамках данного приложения, рядовой пользователь получает права root.

Более подробно можете почитать тут:

http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/unix/glava_15.shtml

Comment: как понять, вот к примеру возьмем IDE Visual Studio ( да речь идет о windows ) там по умолчанию к проекту создается манифест где можно прописать запуск программы от имени администратора. Думаю и в кодблок есть решение

Comment: **манифест где можно прописать запуск программы от имени администратора** - вполне допускаю. Прописать можно всё, что угодно. Манифест - это просто объявление о том, что мы ЖЕЛАЕМ. Но в реальной ОС (даже - Windows) разрешить запуск приложения пользователя с правами администратора может только администратор. Вполне допускаю, что манифест как-то облегчает задачу администратора. Но, если и вправду, рядовой пользователь может присвоить себе права администратора путём написания небольшого текстового файла, то тогда я буду вынужден повторить излюбленный тезис люниксоидов: "Виндовс маст дай!" :-)

Comment: @Sergey, манифест позволяет принудительный запуск от имени администратора (аналог  `ПКМ → Запуск от имени администратора`). Точнее, он позволяет указать, что с ограниченными привилегиями программа всё равно не заработает (административная утилита, к примеру). `Но, если и вправду, рядовой пользователь может присвоить себе права администратора путём написания небольшого текстового файла` – если пользователь мало того что работает под административной учётной записью (по умолчанию), так ещё и UAC (последний рубеж обороны) выключил – он сам себе злобный буратин.